# Getting a MySQL result from joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I am trying to get output from the three tables below:

[image]

1. Domains (containing domain information, including their Customer ID)
2. Customer information
3. History of that domain (containing many records per domain)

I want to have the output of a domain with customer info and its latest item from history per date.

I am using CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->select(
     ->from()
     ->where()
     ->join()
```

Comment: 219 questions asked and still doesn't know how it works...

Comment: trust me i tried all day my best but can't figure out, can you please help

Comment: What SQL have you tried?

Comment: mysql with php and codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

The query you would need is something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM domains d 
 LEFT JOIN customers c ON d.Customer = c.id
 LEFT JOIN history h ON h.domain_id = d.id
 ORDER BY h.date desc
```

You need to put this into Code Igniter yourself - I have guessed some field names, I'm sure you can come up with them.